# Why my Cardview doesn't appear like in layout when i run it

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hello I'm using a Cardview to represent item in my application, below the code layout, I use it in a recycler view, but it is not the same as is the layout. The cardview is completely white and doesn't have corner radius , does anyone know how to help me?

[image]

It appears fine when I go to Design Tab but when I run on Device it appears Different. It has no corner radius or color just have margin how can i fix this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="1dp"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:padding="16dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="32dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/pink"
app:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="16dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardImage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardName"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#673AB7"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBodySize"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**RecyclerView**

```
public class ClothesRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClothesViewHolder> implements Filterable {
List<Clothes> data;
List<Clothes> filteredData;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
private OnItemLongClickListener lListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener=listener;
}
public void setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener){
    lListener =listener;
}


public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
public interface OnItemLongClickListener{
    void onItemLongClick(int position);
}


public ClothesRecycler(List<Clothes> clothes){
    data = clothes;
    filteredData = clothes;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ClothesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.clothes_item_layout,parent,false);

    return new ClothesViewHolder(view,mListener,lListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ClothesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Clothes clothes= data.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(DataConverter.convertByteArray2Image(clothes.getImage()));
        holder.name.setText(clothes.getName());
        holder.bodySize.setText(clothes.getBodySize());
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(clothes.isSelected() ? Color.LTGRAY : Color.WHITE);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

Comment: Post the code of the RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i edit post

Comment: The code of the adapter not the layout with the RecyclerView

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i added to code

Comment: Does the image cover the entire cardview?

Comment: how is it showing when you run the app or it dosnt show at all ?

Comment: @takieddine when i run the app card is displaying with no feature it has not any corner radius or color it showing basically white rectangle only have elevation

Comment: i tried your layout in new project and laucnhed the app and your xml code is working fine , here is an image https://imgur.com/a/FwAD8Nk , take a look , i ll post the xml file below

Comment: did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

- Check this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="32dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardImage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardName"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#673AB7"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardBodySize"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: i actually tried the same exact code in my project and it shows properly , did you try on some other devices with differences screen size ?